# Can I render a column header that contains a string & an imported component when using React Table library?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

Is it possible to render a column header that contains a string & an imported component to resemble something like the following image:

[image: Table Column Header Example]

I've got an arrow sort icon that I've imported that I'd like to include in some headers beside a string value (*e.g.*, Location, First Name, Last Name, *etc.*) to indicate that the columns are sortable. The following code is how I've tried to build one such header:

```
{
    Header: `Location ${<ArrowSort />}`,
    accessor: 'location',
    disableFilters: true
}
```

Rather than the desired output, I'm seeing "Location [object Object] as the column's header. I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong and point me in the right direction to produce the desired header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by rewriting my Header parameter as the following:

```
Header: () => (
  <div className="flex">
    <div className="inline-flex">Location</div>
    <div className="inline-flex">
      <ArrowSort />
    </div>
  </div>
),
```

Comment: Sure. You just made it inline

Answer (score 3):

###### Live Example for experiment

[image: Prakash-React-Table-Example]

```js
// Custom Header Cell component
import React from "react";
const HeaderButton = ({ lablel }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{lablel}</span>
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderButton;

//Usage

import HeaderButton from "./HeaderButton"

//Column Definition

const columns = [
  {
    Header: <HeaderButton lablel="Prefix " />,
    accessor: "name"
  }];
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this answer & providing the example on CodeSandbox. However, this answer seemed a bit more abstracted than what I was currently doing & looking for. I was able to come up with a solution I'm satisfied with, which I've left as an answer in this post. Thanks again.